# How do I get extended REtweets in Node.js with Twitter API? (Only getting a MAX of 140 characters)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, twitter

I am trying to get extended retweets, but I cant seem to get that extra field called **retweeted_status** as a parameter in the result. I don't get any errors when including a parameter called "retweeted_status" and I don't know if it even exists as a parameter in Node.js **since Twitter API docs doesn't include any type of examples or clear information for retweets and I tried to implement methods written in other programming lenguages that I searched in Google** but didn't get any good results at the end. (**Note: tweet_mode only works for Tweets not RETweets!**)

Things I tried:

```
retweeted_status: 'extended' //doesn't work but node.js doesn't give an error
retweeted_status: true       //doesn't work but node.js doesn't give an error
retweeted_status: 1          //doesn't work but node.js doesn't give an error
```

My code is the following (**It never enters the if-condition and if it does it gives the error I mention in the code**):

```
var params = {q: '@Avengers', count: 100, include_rts: 0, tweet_mode: 'extended', retweeted_status: 'extended'}; 
client.get('search/tweets', params, function(error, tweets, response) {
    if (!error) {
      console.log(tweets);
      for(var i=0; i < params.count; i++){

        if (tweets.retweeted_status){ //It never enters this condition
                                      //even if it does I get this error
               //TypeError: Cannot read property 'statuses' of undefined tweets.statuses[i]
          tweets = tweets.retweeted_status;
          var tweet = (JSON.stringify(tweets.statuses[i].full_text)+"\n");
          var string = tweet.replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>{}]/g, '');
          console.log('hi');
        }
        else{
          var tweet = (JSON.stringify(tweets.statuses[i].full_text)+"\n");
          var string = tweet.replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>{}]/g, '');
          console.log('hi2');
        }

        fs.appendFile("tweet.txt", string, function (err) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log('Saved!');
        }); 
      }
    }
});
```

I looked for a few hours into this website https://dev.to/kehers/formatting-tweets-a-look-at-extended-tweets-retweets-and-quotes-n5j and tried to make some code (that I already provided above) which didn't work since the IF-statement got ignored. When getting the tweet it should give an extra parameter "retweeted_status" like below:

```
{
  "created_at": "Sun Mar 11 12:00:27 +0000 2018",
  "id": 972804442667003900,
  "full_text": "RT @jasongorman: As a physics grad, I understand how snooker works at a level I imagine a lot of pro snooker players don't. But I suck at s…",
  "truncated": false,
  "display_text_range": [...],
  "entities": {...},
  "retweeted_status": { // <======================= I am not getting this extra parameter!
    "created_at": "Sun Mar 11 08:10:46 +0000 2018",
    "id": 972746641957642200,
    "full_text": "As a physics grad, I understand how snooker works at a level I imagine a lot of pro snooker players don't. But I suck at snooker. Understanding != ability.",
    "truncated": false,
    "display_text_range": [0, 155],
    "entities": {
      "hashtags": [],
      "symbols": [],
      "user_mentions": [],
      "urls": []
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Alexis 
do you have any update one this?
I am also having the same situation